# Getting all notifications at same time

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I have set notifications using alarm manager for events. If I set multiple notifications at different times then last all notifications also arise at last notification with the last one.

Also I want to cancel the particular notification if the switch is off. I have given the same intent to cancel the notification. But I think all the notifications got cancelled.

Also I have created time tables and events are created using the time table's id. Now if I delete one time table I want to delete all the notifications set to the events that belongs to the deleted time table.

setting alarm:

```
public void setNotificationTime(Calendar c)
{

    Date dateFrom = new Date();
    df = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
    try {
        dateFrom = df.parse(startTime);
    }
    catch (ParseException ex) {

    }

    dateFrom.getTime();
    c.setTime(dateFrom);

    hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    if(notificationTime !=null  &&  !notificationTime.isEmpty()) {


        if (notificationTime.equals("10 Minutes Before")) {

            FLAG = 1;

            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute - 10);
            c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            c.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
            // c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,);

            SetDay(c);

            notification = c.getTime();
            notificationTime = df.format(notification);

           // setAlarm(c, FLAG);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), notificationTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } else if (notificationTime.equals("30 Minutes Before")) {

            FLAG = 2;

            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute - 30);
            c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            c.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
            // c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,);

            SetDay(c);

            notification = c.getTime();
            notificationTime = df.format(notification);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), notificationTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          //  setAlarm(c,FLAG);

        }
```

Notification Receiver

```
public class NotificationReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {


public static int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
NotificationManager notificationManager;
Notification myNotification;

EventTableHelper db;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    Toast.makeText(context, "Time is set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    db = new EventTableHelper(context);

    List<EventData> testSavings = db.getAllEvents();

    for (EventData ts : testSavings) {
        String log = "from date:" + ts.getFromDate()
                + " ,to date: " + ts.getToDate()
                + " ,location: " + ts.getLocation()
                + " ,title " + ts.getTitle();

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = new Date();
        Date date1 = new Date();
        Log.d("Result: ", log);

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

        try {
            date = df.parse(ts.getFromDate());
            date1 = df.parse(ts.getToDate());
        } catch (ParseException ex) {

        }
        String timeFrom = df2.format(date);
     //   String startTime = String.valueOf(timeFrom);

        String timeTo = df2.format(date1);
       // String endTime = String.valueOf(timeTo);


        String location = ts.getLocation();
        String title = ts.getTitle();


        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                0,
                myIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        if(location.equals(""))
        {
            String msg = "From : " + timeFrom + "\nTo : " + timeTo;

            myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle("Event : " + title)
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.eventicon)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .build();

        }

        else
        {
            String msg = "From : " + timeFrom + "\nTo : " + timeTo + "\nAt : " + location;
            myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle("Event : " + title)
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.eventicon)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .build();

        }

        Log.i("Notify", "Notification");
        notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);

        myNotification.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra("notificationId",MY_NOTIFICATION_ID);

        MY_NOTIFICATION_ID ++;

    }


 }
}
```

Comment: The Calendar class is horrible for manipulating dates and times. I suggest you take a look at [joda-time-android](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android)

Comment: why db.getAllEvents() ??

Comment: to get event details from database.@Zoedia

Answer (score 1):

You reset MY_NOTIFICATION_ID every time the broadcastReceiver is called so all the notifications have the same id, which is 0.
What I did to avoid it was to use:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int id = rand.nextInt(1000000) + 1;
```

so that every notification will definitely get a different id number (chance of 1 in a million it will repeat itself).

Comment: i tried this , but i want notification to repeat every week. it's not repeating. @Morza

Comment: I can think of 3 ways to handle it: 1. Set a repeating alarm that sends the notification every week (I'm not sure how it works because I've never tried it). 2. Set the notification again to next week every time it pops up, with a new id number. 3. Save the id number in SharedPreferences and get it from there.